# Highcharts :: Pie :: Add icon for specific series

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using **Highcharts 5.0.7** pie charts.

Need to highlight one of data item by inserting icons before and after that.

By targeting series name (**Highlight**) I am able insert some dynamic code to it by using Highcharts formater option like below which is not working :(

```
formatter: function () {
  if (this.point.name == 'Highlight') {
    return '<div class="ptit-icon PieTimerIconTop">Top</div><div class="ptit-icon PieTimerIconBottom">Bottom</div>';                                    
  }
},
```

How can I insert icon (before & after) for highlight slice?

**What I want:**

[image]

**What I am getting:**

[image]

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oqn31cpe/2/)

> Code

```
$(function () {
  var colors = ['#0d8aff', '#bc2f20', '#31ccfd', '#fd8f40'];
  pieData = [           
    { name: "", color: '#eaeaec', y: 50 },
    { name: "", color: '#97cc00', y: 12.5 },
    { name: "Highlight", color: '#5ba528', y: 12.5, className: "markerHighlight" },
    { name: "", color: '#b2d844', y: 12.5 },
    { name: "", color: '#97cc00', y: 12.5 }
  ];
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'chartContainer',
      type: 'pie',
      height: 250,
      width: 250,
      borderRadius: 0
    },
    credits: { enabled: false },
    title: false,
    tooltip: false,
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        startAngle: -45,
        innerSize: '95%',
        size: '100%',
        shadow: false,
        dataLabels: false,
      },
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          useHTML: true,
          formatter: function () {
            if (this.point.name == 'Highlight') {
              return '<div class="ptit-icon PieTimerIconTop">Top</div><div class="ptit-icon PieTimerIconBottom">Bottom</div>';                                  
            }
          },
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: pieData,
    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have disabled dataLabels - you have to enable them. Then, you should correctly position and set **background-size** style for elements with arrow.

```
.ptit-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 10px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7g8249nh/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Thanks for your time. But, it is not working if value changes though. Eg: Highlight value (this will be dynamic) I have adjusted where arrows are fixed to earlier position. http://jsfiddle.net/7g8249nh/2/

Comment: Hi Reddy, Yes you are right,  this solution solves problem only in one case. Please take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/52fz1vmL/, I used gauge series to create more elastic solution.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time **@ppotaczek**, but still this does not solve the problem :(... I want to put marker at start of the point and end of the point. After changing value to 152.2 (this will be dynamic)  `name: "Highlight"`, arrows are still in fixed position. http://jsfiddle.net/52fz1vmL/3/

Comment: Hi Reddy, this solution requires settings of right values for yAxis max and gauge data, but it can be done dynamically in a very simple way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lt2km4jd/

Comment: **@ppotaczek**, Excellent, this is what exactly I am looking for. Thanks for your wonderful support. I am **Accepting** and **Upvoting** your answer. Thanks again for your time